# Local HTML files won't open in any browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

A friend of mine is working on a mac running Yosemite, and for some reason no browser is able to open local HTML files. I tried it on a different computer and it opened just fine, so I know it's not the HTML file itself. When trying to open it, Safari opens a new empty tab with "Top Sites," Chrome did absolutely nothing, and he's about to try on Firefox but I fear the same thing. When using the Sublime Text "View in Browser" package, no browser is triggered and nothing happens. Default browser is set as Safari.

Any thoughts as to what could be causing this? I've never experienced such a thing before. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I have an perfect answer.

For Mac:

Goto Text Edit > Preferences. Then under 'New Document', select 'Plain text'. And under 'Open and save', Check both 'Display html file as html code' and 'Display RTF file as RTF code'. Uncheck 'Add ".txt" ' option.

Then save your html code in TextEdit in .html format.

This should work for Chrome and Safari.